# Appgyver Steroids + Jquery mobile + Phonegap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, steroids

I am currently using jquery mobile and [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap) frameworks to build mobile applications.

The performance and pace of mobile apps are low when Jquery Mobile combined with Phonegap and comparitively high when Appgyver [steroids](/questions/tagged/steroids) is worked with [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap). However I am not sure about applying all the above said frameworks together.

Is there any possibility to be more elloborate on how to combine Appgyver [steroids](/questions/tagged/steroids), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) mobile and [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap)? I would really appreciate if I can get a real example and tutorial on the usage and resultant on the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Personally, I've found the tutorials on AppGyver's page for getting starting with Steroids very useful. However, the documentation on how to integrate existing Phonegap plugins could stand a little improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JQuery Mobile is optimized to work across a large amount of devices and browsers, not just within phonegap so it might be better to use different specialized frameworks for what you are doing.

Steriods recommends angular for javascript modeling and topcoat for ui enhancements.

JQuery mobile handles everything from mobile styles to page navigation and history.  You could use JQuery mobile for just styling and then use steroids for navigation and page transitions.

AppGyver has switched to using Ionic for it's default framework now.  Ionic is built on Angular JS but it is specifically optimized for using within PhoneGap.  You can even create a phonegap project with their command line tools.  They also released an awesome plugin to fix the dreaded keyboard issue on android and ios.  I'm hoping to switch over from Jquery Mobile to Ionic as soon as time allows.